# jMeter how to make user wait until the previous loop is done

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter, so please bare with me if I have asked a silly question. I have a thread where I want to run that thread like 100 times. In the thread I have scripts like

1. Add a member to a mailbox,
2. Get the mailbox details and confirm the member added was displayed
3. update the member role in that mailbox
4. Delete the member from that mailbox

I am using same mailbox and user for my test for my loop. Here the issue is the same member cannot be added to the same mailbox unless we delete that member from that mailbox.
So when I run the test with just 5 iterations, the add script for first iteration was passed and next 4 iterations for that add script getting failed. Because the first thread already added the user to that mailbox and while the second user tries to add the same user it fails, that's expected.

Steps I tried:

I even tried using constant timer in my add script to wait for 4secs so my previous user actions should be done. That's my understanding. Please correct me if that's wrong.

The other thing I tried was ramp-up time to 8 secs and then the script for 5 users ran fine. But when I increase the users to 50 then almost 50% of the scripts failed.

Here comes my problem. How do I make the second user to wait until the first user done with the delete script, so second user can use the same data and so on.
Attached are some screens of my scripts

[image: Test plan]

[image: Mailbox member thread]

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) should represent a real user with its own credentials and mailbox. Credentials and/or mailbox can be [parameterized](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide), normally people use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to provide test data for JMeter scripts

If you have only one user/mailbox - you won't be able to use more than 1 thread (virtual user) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), to wit if you need to run the scenario 100 times - you need to set it up like:

[image]

Another option is using [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller). But be aware that there will be no concurrency (only 1 user will be running the test at a time), if you need to have more - you will need to use different credentials for different users

Comment: Hello @Dmitri, Thanks for your reply. If I do like loop but not as 100 users then I can't get the actual through put of that sampler right? Also what I understand from different credentials is that I need to user 100 mailbox ids with 100 members to run the same script 100 times so that won't fail. If I have to do that do I also need to specify 100 users in my authentication thread.